# SQL Collate statement where clause

Tags: sql-server, multilingual, non-ascii-characters, collate

I am trying following query in  SQL Server 2008 R2. While working with accent sensitivity I found this:

```
select case when 'Наина' = '毛泽东先生' then 'Match' else 'No Match' end col
```

I see result is:

`'Match'`

What could be possibly be the reason for this behavior? I have also tried using `COLLATE` with different accents but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `NVARCHAR` in your comparison. Upon checking, both strings are converted to `'?????'` when using `VARCHAR`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
    (N'Наина', 'Наина'),
    (N'毛泽东先生', '毛泽东先生')
)t([NVACRHAR], [VARCHAR])
```

The result of the above query:

```
NVACRHAR     VARCHAR
--------     -------
Наина        ?????
毛泽东先生    ?????
```

So, in order to achieve the desired result, you must use `NVARCHAR`:

```
select 
    case 
        when 'Наина' = '毛泽东先生'  then 'Match' 
        else 'No Match' 
    end match_VARCHAR,
    case 
        when N'Наина' = N'毛泽东先生' then 'Match' 
        else 'No Match' 
    end match_NVARCHAR
```

---

Edit: I don' really have the real explanation, the above just shows the result of my testing. Another answer might explain this better.

Comment: I suggest you post another question for that. I'm not really that familiar to linq.